# DIVs, height and float

Tags: css, html

I have float red divs on blue div like on picture 
[image]

```
<div class="blue">
  <div style="height: 40px; float: left"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px; float: left"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px; float: left"></div>

  <div style="height: 40px; float: left"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px; float: left"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

I want to do, so blue div have height on red DIVs. When I remove float it's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add display:table-cell; or overflow:hidden; to your blue div. This will give the parent the height of it's children.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ueAK5/2/)

like this:

```
.blue{
   overflow:hidden;
   //or
   //display:table-cell;
}
```

a sidenote - your divs need a width when they are floating.

You also have the option to make your div with class blue float. But this might cause some unwanted behavior in your document (if the div is not supposed to float).

Comment: @PeterVR But there's actually no content to display, that's only for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply float the blue div:

```
.blue{
   float: left;
}
```

It will then expand to take on the height of its children.

**If floating is not an option**, I would set `display` to `inline-block` to make it behave the same way as a floated element.

```
.blue{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common problem known as the 'clearfix' problem. More info can be found (for example) here: [Div rendering incorrectly in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797667/div-rendering-incorrectly-in-firefox/15798326#15798326)

In short, you should add a class `.clearfix` to you parent (blue) div that looks something like this:

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
  }
&:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

This one is 'borrowed' from Twitter Bootsrap, bu there are many alternatives out there. For why and how it works, I suggest googling 'clearfix'.

Note that there exist other 'fixes' like working with `inline blocks`, adding a `overflow: hidden` or even displaying as `table-cell`. Though they might work in some situation, they almost all have other side-effects, or are not fully cross browser, so they should be used with care.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something clean and more dynamic, try this:

```
<div class="blue">
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

And this:

```
.blue {background-color: blue;text-align: center;display: inline-block;padding: 5px;}
.blue > div > div {background-color: red; width:100px; height: 50px; margin: 10px;display: inline-block;}
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5dy7/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option without compatibility in all browsers options but without the need of float:left

```css
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 140px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blue div{
    background-color:red;
    margin: 2.5px 0 2.5px 0;
    width:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px;"></div>

  <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
</div>
```